# How can I use python's cProfile to profile a django app while running on gunicorn

Tags: python, django, profiler, gunicorn, cprofile

How can I profile a Django application while running on gunicorn using python cProfile.

I can profile in development mode:
`python -m cProfile -o sample.profile manage.py runserver`

But what should I do when it is running in production server using gunicorn?

Comment: Thought `web: args` works in foreman but guess what `I'm not`
 ...!

Comment: I don't think there's any good way to use cProfile to profile a django app running under gunicorn.  What is it you need to figure out?  I've found it most useful to use the logging system to track how long my views take to execute.

Comment: You can take a look at this profiler for Django : https://github.com/django-silk/silk
It uses cProfile internally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run it this way using gunicorn.

```
$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=myapp.settings python -m cProfile -o output_file ../env/bin/gunicorn --workers=8 --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 myapp.wsgi:application
```